# What's the best way of adding a custom centre button to a tab bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Many apps have a standard tab bar with a custom button in the centre which performs some special function. Some examples can be found here:

http://mobile-patterns.com/custom-tab-navigation

What's the best way of implementing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/) you can see how to implement that button. I am gonna paste the code so it stays here forever:

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

CGFloat heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
if (heightDifference < 0)
    button.center = self.tabBar.center;
else
{
    CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
    center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
    button.center = center;
}

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: on push the button stays even i am hiding the tab bar, any solutn for that

Comment: How do you set the spacing from the other buttons though?

Answer (score 8):

I got Franciso's code working with a few minor tweaks. I placed the code in the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of a standard Tab Bar Application template in Xcode 4.1. I believe Xcode 4.2 may have a different template.

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabItemOff.png"];
UIImage *highlightImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabItemSelected.png"];
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
CGFloat heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
if (heightDifference < 0)
    button.center = self.tabBarController.tabBar.center;
else
{
    CGPoint center = self.tabBarController.tabBar.center;
    center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
    button.center = center;
}
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Hi Cannyboy, I've added your code and it worked but the button does nothing. how can I map this button to the tab underneath it so that when I click that button it will take me to that viewcontroller.

Comment: @Ankur Its just a button. so you need to write your own target method for that and select the center tab bar item in that method and dont forget to set the selected button image for your uibutton.. then you can achieve what you desire..