# Dismissing a viewcontroller that is presented from UITabBarController in the app delegate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

To achieve a similar effect to many photo apps I:

1. Set up my tab bar programmatically in the App delegate
2. Added a custom button on top of a tab bar item that I would like to use to launch the camera
   (basically using this method: [What's the best way of adding a custom centre button to a tab bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527192/whats-the-best-way-of-adding-a-custom-centre-button-to-a-tab-bar))
3. Created a view controller that handles the camera functionality

I launch the view controller this way from the button and it works. However, I can't dismiss it effectively.

in ***didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*** :

```
 var tabBC = UITabBarController()
 //....

 shutterButton.addTarget(self, action: "presentCamera:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
 tabBC.view.addSubview(shutterButton)
```

action attached:

```
func presentCamera(sender: AnyObject){
    let composeSB = UIStoryboard(name: "Compose", bundle: nil) as UIStoryboard
    let composeVC = composeSB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("composeVC") as ComposeViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(composeVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

In ***ComposeViewController*** this method gets called but the view controller does not get dismissed. I would think this would dismiss the VC and I would see the views in the tabbarcontroller.

```
func cameraOverlayDidCancel() {

   // I've tried:

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)    
  //self.view.parentViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: The first method you tried should have worked, so it's hard to say why it didn't. The last method you show wouldn't work, because self.view doesn't have a parentViewController property. You could try self.parentViewController!.dismiss... and self.view.window!.rootViewController!.dismiss... and see if either of those works.

Comment: @rdelmar If I try self.parentViewController! I get an unexpectedly nil value for parentViewController. Do you think this is somehow because I'm not presenting the view correctly? It doesn't have a parent? I've orphaned it...

Comment: Oh, sorry. That should have been self.presentingViewController.

Comment: @rdelmar what should have been self.presentingViewController?

Comment: Instead of self.parentViewController

Comment: When I try that I get this error: attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self = <UITabBarController: 0x14550f580> modalViewController = <appName.ComposeViewController: 0x145606580> @rdelmar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75880/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-sophie-fader).

Comment: @sophie fader Are you sure your code call 'cameraOverlayDidCancel' method in main thread?